# jQuery Ajax Complete but not this function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    tips();
});
```

Which runs the tips function again when an ajax event completes! However the tips function ALSO contains ajax requests so it calls itself which isn't what I want to do!

How could I run tips when ajax events complete EXCEPT if it's the tips ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

**Don't use my solution. Use the one from mmcnickle below.**

---

In your `tips();` function could you set a bool flag? Something like...

```
var isTips = false;

function tips(callBack){
   isTips = true;
   // rest of your code
   if(typeOf(callBack) == 'function'){
      callBack();
   }
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   if(!isTips){
      tips(function(){
         isTips = false;
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: or just create tips as a function.

Comment: tips is a function, what do you mean?

Comment: This solution could lead to some very odd behaviour and could be the source of some hard to track bugs.

a) The `isTips` flag is never set to `false` again, so after the first call to `tips()`, your `ajaxComplete()` callback won't work for any more ajax calls, regardless if they were called by `tips()` or not.

b) Ajax requests that complete between the time you set the `isTips` flag and setting it false again, will fail to trigger the callback.

See my answer for a solution that allows to check _per request_ whether or not to call `tips()`.

Comment: I would have thought that he would be able to figure that out for himself. With my solution, you could always set isTips back to false after calling `tips();` in the `ajaxComplete` function.

Answer (score 4):

The callback function for `ajaxComplete()` can be set up to receive details about the ajax request. You can then pass in a special setting when making the ajax call that allows you to tell when you should, or shouldn't call the tips function:

```
function tips() {
    var settings = {
        is_tips_call: true
    };

    $.ajax('#', settings);

    alert("In tips");
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {

    if ('is_tips_call' in settings && settings.is_tips_call == true) {
        // Do nothing
        return;
    }

    tips();

});
```

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJCEf/2/) for this so you can see it in action. This is preferable to the accepted answer, see my comments for details.

Comment: No, it is necessary to check on each request to ensure that all non-tips calls are actually caught. Because these are asynchronous calls, you can't say for certain that there will be no callbacks between the time you set `isTips = true` and `isTips = false`. If any callbacks do get fired during that time, you miss it.

Comment: Damn it you're right. :-P This is an elegant solution. I hate being wrong, but I will admit that I am :)